# Persian(farsi) long texts aren't shown correctly in columns in highcharts gantt

Tags: highcharts

in this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/meysamm22/mghyznco/22/), the columns' cells contain some long Persian(Farsi) texts, so you can see the position of the texts is incorrect in the Gantt chart as well as its exports. but also, if I replace these texts with English ones, their position will be correct!

I've written a sample text manually just for making an example.

```
columns: [
          {
            title: {
              text: 'First Column'
            },
            useHTML: true,
            labels: {
              format: 'نتاکم کنمت کمنت کمنتشس اکمسنتشیکنمیتیک تک تکنتسی ن خهت کمنت من کمنت کمنت ه کمنت ',
              align: 'center',
              style: {
              direction: 'rtl',
                overflowWrap: 'break-word',
                wordWrap: 'break-word',
                width: '350px'

              }
            }
          
          }
         ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `align` to `left` should fix the issue.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bhm3yqvo/

```
  columns: [{
    title: {
      text: 'First Column'
    },
    labels: {
      format: 'نتاکم کنمت کمنت کمنتشس اکمسنتشیکنمیتیک تک تکنتسی ن خهت کمنت من کمنت کمنت ه کمنت ',
      align: 'left'
    } 
  }]
```

---

EDIT:

According to the comments below - another solution which came to my mind is to use the `formatter` callback to render those labels as standalone HTML elements. I need to point one thing - the script which is used in this demo is a script from the master branch, because of this bug - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10281 - it will work fine with the regular script after the next version release.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q8wx2egL/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in Persian, we write from right to left. is there another way to fix this in RTL way?

Comment: @MeysamZarei " but in Persian, we write from right to left" - I am not sure if this matters, in this case, would you reproduce some case when it will be not working?

Comment: Let me clarify it, in my example in the question, you can see the problem when I set the `align` to `right`, because in Persian literature we start writing from the right of papers, so it doesn't make sense writing a long text which starts from the left of a column's cell.

Comment: To be sure - would you like to have this text on the centre, but the second line for the long text should start from the right site?

Comment: Yes, both of the lines should start from the right/center of the cell, I also have this problem in the `center` align, you can see it in my example in my question.

Comment: Are sure the mentioned example in the edit section is correct? because there is no change than my example! I mean there is also the main problem

Comment: @MeysamZarei my mistake, I have tested it on the chart wide less than 650px and seems fine under this value. It breaks for the more wide chart. Actually, I found that it doesn't work properly also in the Highcharts, so it doesn't look like the Gantt problem. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6gsvr8tm/

Comment: Yes, I see, so what workaround can be helpful for this problem?

Comment: I don't know Persian, could you confirm if this text is fine? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f5hj61ry/

Comment: @MeysamZarei, ok I have changed the demo link in the edited post, please check it - to me it seems fine - also test all demos in the other browsers, because each browser could read the `RTL` signs differently - for example your main demo looks fine in the FF.

Comment: It's ok for the highcharts, but in the gantt chart has not totally fixed. Please take a look at this one: https://jsfiddle.net/meysamm22/mghyznco/35/

Comment: @MeysamZarei, how about this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0sje2az4/? And have you taken a look at this case in different browsers?

Comment: It's shown correctly in firefox but in chrome, it is not shown correctly

Comment: To be honest - I am not sure what to do in this case, it could be an Chrome issue. What about the last demo which I shared? Is it correct?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I will fix this issue in my case by manipulating some solutions which you mentioned, but it's better to report this issue on GitHub page of Highcharts. Thanks for your collaboration